# executable(hello) is not created,objects files of two programmes has been created

Tags: c

```
#!bin/bash
CC=gcc /*gcc compiler*/
CFLAGS=-I. /*current working directory*/
hello: p1.o p2.o p.h /*hello is the executable i want to create*/
    $(cc) -o hello p1.o p2.o p.h -I.
```

the error showing is that

```
o hello p1.o p2.o p.h -I.
make: o: Command not found
make: [hello] Error 127 (ignored)
```

by doing make it is creating object files of the codes but the executable hello is not created

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`make`'s variables are case-sensitive. You need to write

```
$(CC) -o hello p1.o p2.o p.h -I.
```

Since `$(cc)` is unset, `make` will attempt to execute `-o hello ...`. A leading dash suppresses errors in `make` syntax, so the resulting command is the `o hello ...` that you see.